# Historic flight info from 2013

Tags: air-travel, airlines, delays, compensation, connecting-flights

Where can I find historic flight info about past delays?
I was flying with Air France flight from Paris to Tampa (through New York) on 13 November 2013.
My flight was delayed either in Paris or in New York. I can't remember which. I just learnt that you can claim for delays so I want to find out how long the delay was. (and where) Could any one of you check this please?

Flight info: 
AF0006 from Paris to JFK  scheduled departure 14:10

AF9534 from JFK to TPA   scheduled departure 18:45